# Grunt read .json file to concat list of html files

Tags: javascript, html, json

I’m trying to get grunt to concat some .css files from 2 different directories into a single css file

I got it working ok and am trying to write a similar piece of code to concat html files in the order I specify in a simple external .json file rather than editing the Grunfile.js directly each time but it keeps throwing errors

The file locations and permissions are all ok, I can do it with php or concat the css files ok, I’m not great on js syntax os using functions. I only learned to use Grunt in the last few days so am pretty sure have not called the file with the correct code??

Any advice kindly appreciated!

This is my Gruntfile.js exactly

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // 1. All configuration goes here

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {  
        // 2. Configuration for concatinating files goes here

        file.readJSON(‘html-files.json’);

    },

    watch: {
          files: ['../../pages/**/*.html’],
          tasks: ['concat'],
          options : { nospawn : true }
        }
    });

    // 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    // 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);

};
```

This is the html-files.json file contents exactly

```
html: {

    src: [
        '../../pages/**/this-block.html',

        '../../pages/**/that-block.html',
    ],

    dest: '../../somepage/content.html',
}
```

Comment: `'../../pages/**/*.html’` - why the wrong quote symbol at the end of that line?

Comment: What kinds of errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for looking! The syntax or quotes etc are probably wrong, I'm not super good at js yet

Comment: When I typed 'grunt' in the cli it said unexpected token, when I was first messing around with the css concat before I got that working it just kept saying error, unexpected token, no default task found .. something like that. Once I got the syntax right it just worked. Sorry I don't know more.. Can screenshot it if easier or copy and paste it exactly

Comment: Should it be "../../pages/**/*.html" instead? .. thanks!